# How to increase timeout in secureTextEntry

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to increase the timeout given to a user after he's typed a character in secureTextEntry of a TextInput, can I have any direction of how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]